# Excel Advanced Filter the most recent date

Tags: excel

I have a data set like:

```
ID  DC1     Date
1   sth1    2015-01-01 
1   sth2    2016-01-01
1   sth3    2012-01-01
2   sth2    2014-01-01
2   sth3    2012-01-01
```

and would like to take the most recent record for each ID.

```
ID  DC1     Date
1   sth2    2016-01-01
2   sth2    2014-01-01
```

Is there any advanced filter option that facilitates that or do I have to write a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sort your data by `ID` and `Date` descending and then remove the duplicates.
Of couse, if you need to keep your data then you should copy the data set to a new sheet or so before doing this :)

---

**Sort**

[image: Sort Data]

---

**Remove Duplicates**

[image: Remove Duplicates]

---

**Result**
[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you just one more question. Sort shows me the sort options "A-Z" and "Z-A" how can I change it to "Newest to Oldest" for the date column?

Comment: If you change the data type of the cells to Date then it should switch to "Newest to Oldest"

Answer (score 1):

You want an array formula.

For example:

```
{=MAX(IF(C8:C10=$F$8,D8:D10))}
```

C8:C10 are the category names

D8:D10 are the dates

F8 is the category you want the most recent date for

Note: The curly brackets cannot be typed. They must be toggled by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER whilst editing the formula.